# Rails 5 joining activerecord scopes with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to join 2 scopes with OR.

```
scope :unassigned, -> {
  where(dongle_id: nil)
}

scope :driverless, -> {
  left_outer_joins(:customer).where(customers: { id: nil })
}
```

Now I am doing this as I can't figure it out:

```
scope :inactive, -> {
  left_outer_joins(:customer).where(
    'customers.vehicle_id IS ? OR vehicles.dongle_id IS ?', nil, nil
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A scope represents a narrowing of a database query, such as where(color: :red).select('shirts.*').includes(:washing_instructions) (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope)

Joining scopes using OR condition is not possible. A scope narrows resultset with some filter. Chaining scopes together is equivalent to using scope filters at the same time, ie SQL's AND condition.

For your case when 2 scopes need to be joined with OR you could merge their resultsets:

```
Vehicle.unassigned.to_a | Vehicle.driverless.to_a
```

but it's better to write another scope, as you already did.

Comment: Yeah, doing it in memory with `to_a` is terrible.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
scope :inactive, -> { unassigned.or(driverless) }
```

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't work: `Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:left_outer_joins]`

Comment: Have you tried `scope :inactive, -> { driverless.or(unassigned) }`? Note the change between driverless and unassigned ... this way the join is outside the `or` logic

Comment: I tried both :S. The `left_outer_join` is the problem. The other answer points that out as well.